# Debugging Code After Batch File Reinstall of Plugin

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2022, devenv

I have a windows forms app that is developed as a plugin for another application.  When the parent application starts, the plugin is loaded.

For debugging, the manual process is to:

1. Make code changes
2. Rebuild the setup project
3. Uninstall the application
4. Re-Install the application
5. Start debugging (note, VS has "start external program" set on the project and starts the parent application for the plugin at this point)... I have the modules set to load and at this point I can hit new breakpoints on any code changes and debug normally.

The problem starts when I try to add some automation.  I wrote a method to prompt the developer on application start if they want to uninstall/build/reinstall the project before continuing debugging.  If they choose 'yes' a batch file is created that performs those operations and then the developer is prompted to start debugging again.

PROBLEM HERE:
**Even though the project has been uninstalled/built/reinstalled, when the developer starts debugging again, the symbols are out of sync, the new code changes get skipped and breakpoints put on the new code are not hit.**

How do I make it so (*in code*) that when the debugger is restarted, it recognizes the code changes and allows for debugging the new code?

Here is my method for performing the work described above:

```
public static void AskDeveloperIfRebuildReqd()
{
    //app was already rebuilt, just continue with debugging
    if (!Properties.Settings.Default.PromptForDebugRebuild)
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.PromptForDebugRebuild = true;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        return;
    }
    
    DialogResult dr = MessageBox.Show("Do you want to rebuild and re-install the plugin for debugging?", "Rebuild?", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo);
    
    if (dr == DialogResult.Yes)
    {
        //--these are relevent directories--
        string projectPath = Environment.CurrentDirectory.Substring(0, Environment.CurrentDirectory.IndexOf("bin"));
        string solnPath = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(projectPath, @"..\"));
        string setupProjectPath = string.Format("{0}MyDomain.MyProject.Setup", solnPath);
    
        //--these are paths to files used below--
        string solnFile = string.Format("{0}MyDomain.MyProject.sln", solnPath);
        string setupProjectFile = string.Format("{0}\\MyDomain.MyProject.Setup.vdproj", setupProjectPath);
        string msiInstallFile = string.Format("{0}\\Debug\\MyApp.msi", setupProjectPath);
    
        string batFile = string.Format("{0}rebuild.bat", solnPath);
    
        //--these are batch functions--
        //quiet uninstall bat command
        string batUninstallFn = string.Format("MsiExec /uninstall \"{0}\" /quiet", msiInstallFile);
        string batBuildFn = string.Format("devenv \"{0}\" /Project \"{1}\" /Build \"Debug\"", solnFile, setupProjectFile);
        string batInstallFn = string.Format("MsiExec /i \"{0}\" /quiet", msiInstallFile);
    
        //delete the contents of the bat file
        using (System.IO.FileStream fs = new System.IO.FileStream(batFile, System.IO.FileMode.Open)) { fs.SetLength(0); }
    
        //write the batch functions into the file
        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = System.IO.File.CreateText(batFile))
        {
            sw.WriteLine(batUninstallFn);
            sw.WriteLine(batBuildFn);
            sw.WriteLine(batInstallFn);
        }
    
        //run the batch file to uninstall/build/reinstall
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(batFile).WaitForExit();
    
        Properties.Settings.Default.PromptForDebugRebuild = false;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    
        MessageBox.Show("Project has been rebuilt, restart debugging", "Restart Debugging");                     
    }
    else
    {
        Properties.Settings.Default.PromptForDebugRebuild = true;
        Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
    }
    
    return;
}
```

Here's an image of how debugging looks with a newly added string after the above method runs

[image]

If I had done the process manually as shown in the steps in the first part of the question, I would be able to see the value for this string.

Comment: did you turn off the just my code?

Comment: "Just my Code" was disabled.  I re-enabled it and ran again but the issue is the same.  What I don't understand is, why if I do the uninstall/rebuild/reinstall manually, debugging works but, if I do it in code, debugging does not work.  I added a screenshot above after running the project following the code uninstall/rebuild/reinstall.

Comment: Also, just as a double check, I used dotpeek to decompile the published code to verify that the changes got published (in case of img above the "myString" var) and the changes do exist in the code.